# Network not starting when logging into 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, netplan, systemd-networkd

I am having to run the following command everytime I login to my Ubuntu

```
sudo netplan apply
```

I am unsure what I have done to make it only start when I run this command and I am wondering how I go about fixing it so that the network netplan starts automatically.

If you need me to copy and paste files please let me know which files you need.

I have tried to see if systemctl status netplan was working but it says Unit netplan.service could not be found. So I take it I have not added it to systemctl, wondering how would I add this please.

here is my netplan located at /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.20/27
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            match:
                macaddress: E0:D5:5E:02:29:84
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.23.2
                - 8.8.8.8
                search:
                - exemplary
            set-name: eth0
```

@dpb this was a new install fresh from Ubuntu own website..
as for /run/systemd/network it's a folder not a text editor file.

inside that it has the following.

```
File: 10-netplan-eth0.link                        

[Match]
MACAddress=E0:D5:5E:02:29:84

[Link]
Name=eth0
WakeOnLan=off
```

as well as

```
File: 10-netplan-eth0.network             Modified  

[Match]
MACAddress=E0:D5:5E:02:29:84
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
Address=192.168.0.20/27
Gateway=192.168.0.1
DNS=192.168.0.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
Domains=exemplary

[DHCP]
UseMTU=true
RouteMetric=100
```

under /run/systemd/netif
I have 3 folders leases, links, lldp and a file named state

Comment: At boot time, what are the contents of /run/systemd/network and /run/systemd/netif?  Also, was this a new install?  upgrade?

Comment: Also, what file are you modifying to write your netplan configuration?  Type out the file path in your question, and paste the contents in please.

Comment: @dpb this was a new install fresh from Ubuntu own website..
as for /run/systemd/network it's a folder - I have edited the question to show the files inside folders

Comment: add the netplan code.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry.  I jumped ahead of myself a bit.  Are you using desktop or server?

Comment: Also, hopefully to save RTT, if you are using server, please append `sudo systemctl systemd-networkd status`, `ip addr`

Comment: @RussellHarrower are those the contents of /run/systemd/network before or after you have run 'netplan apply'?  The contents match your netplan config so it looks like it may be after.  We might want to compare the before/after here.